# Can't remove old OG: Title <meta property> from website

Tags: html, wordpress, properties, title, meta

I have taken over an old website, which has already an OG: Title, descriptions, image etc set as  in the head tag and I can't seem to remove it.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yChob.png).
I have managed to overwrite this so it looks good in at least facebook when I link my website but there are many other sites that use my old information instead when they collect data from my site. 
If you inspect my head tag you will see my problem, [website](https://weoptimizeltd.com/). (The English title and description is what I want to remove for good).
The meta tags can't be found anywhere in the code or in any plugins that I use such as Yoast SEO.
Is there a way for me to delete the meta property og:title in the database with SQL or something? I'm completely lost on this.

Comment: can you paste the code from your header.php theme?

Comment: Disabled all your plugins step by step by step and also try to switch the default theme and check.

Comment: This is the code inside my head tag on the child themes header: 
https://weoptimizeltd.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Screen-Shot-2018-06-18-at-11.48.47.png

And this is the code inside head tag on the orginal theme: 
https://weoptimizeltd.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Screen-Shot-2018-06-18-at-11.53.28.png